# How can I update a custom Java module into JRE image

Tags: java, java-module, jlink, javapackager

I have a Java desktop application that is a valid module with its module-info.java file. I'm also using javapackager command to create a custom JRE runtime image and then use Inno Setup to create a Windows installer for my application.  Since my application is installed in the custom JRE image as a module, is it possible to update it?  I dont want to update my application using javapackager, just update my application's module into the existing custom JRE image.

I noticed that using javac command and module-patch parameter it could be possible but I'm not really sure how to use it.  Anyone knows what command and parameters I can use to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: jlink incorporates the modules into a custom bin/java[.exe] in the image, so updates probably are not possible.

Comment: Looks like you are looking possibly for [patching a module](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#xoverride)? But that's primarily intended *for testing and debugging. Its use in production settings is strongly discouraged.* More details - http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Patching-module-content